# Cannot post form data to API

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch-api

I have an app where I need to submit form data to an API. It's not working, whether I use JQuery or Axios or Fetch, no matter what API I request, no matter what client is performing the request. I decided to start from scratch using Typicode JSONPlaceholder, copy-pasting much of their own example code, and I still can't query a goddamn API. Somebody please point something out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Post Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <script>
        $(() => {
            $('button').on('click', () => {
                let formData = {
                    title: $('#title').val(),
                    body: $('#body').val(),
                    userId: 0
                };
                fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify(formData),
                    headers: {
                        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
                    }
                })
                .then(response => 
                {
                    response.json()
                })
                .then(json => console.log(json))
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input placeholder="Title" id="title" />
        <textarea placeholder="Body" id="body" rows="4" cols="12"></textarea>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Edited for more information: It seems that JQuery is selecting the elements, and saving their values to the formData object. The debugger assures me  this. And I'm quite certain the servers are receiving the browser's request. I can't speak for the JSONPlaceholder server, but when I used my own server the API always seemed to recognize the request. In fact, when I test my API using Postman it always responds with the proper data. But when I try to build a Javascript client to send the request, the data is never displayed in the console like I ask. And no errors are shown.

Comment: Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  What happens when you debug?  Is the code executed as expected?  Do the jQuery selectors find the elements you expect?  Does `formData` have what you expect?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?

Comment: The elements are selected, and saved to the formData object. The debugger assures me this. I can't speak for the JSONPlaceholder server, but when I used my own server the API seemed to recognize the request. In fact, when I test my API using Postman it always responds with the proper data. But when I try to build a Javascript client to send the request, the data is never displayed in the console. And no errors are shown.

Comment: Note that "can't query the API" and "can't display the data I get back from the API" are two *very* different things.  If you are successfully querying the API and just not displaying the data, then it seems the answer below should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The callback function that you pass to the first `.then` call doesn't return anything

```
.then(response => {
    response.json()
})
```

Change that to `.then(response => response.json())` or `.then(response => {return response.json()})` and it should work.

```js
let formData = {
    title: "title",
    body: "body",
    userId: 0
};
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
})
.then(response => 
{
    return response.json()
})
.then(json => console.log("response",json))
```

Comment: @L.C.J Yes, I've tested it, it works. See the snipped that I've added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with the following. This appears to work as expected.

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function(e) {
    var myData = {
      title: $('#title').val(),
      body: $('#body').val(),
      userId: 1
    };
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(myData),
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h3>Add Item</h3>
<label>Title</label> <input type="text" id="title" /><br/>
<label>Body</label>
<textarea id="body"></textarea><br/>
<button>Send</button>
```

More details at https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder